# target input with classname and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I target a specific input by its class name and value?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="3">
```

Target className something + value 2:

```
$('target classname = something, value = 2').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[class=something][value=2]').prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$('input[class=something][value=2]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="something" value="3">
```

Comment: I'd usually suggest text to explain an answer, but it's so incredibly basic I don't think it warrants wone..

Answer (score 1):

To be specific include the type of the input which doesnt affect the other input types.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][class=something][value=2]').prop('checked',true);
```

If the value is dynamic then use **.val()** method and compare.